# mysql search 2 tables with overlap

Tags: php, mysql, join

i have 2 tables, see below - profiles is my main/master table

```
  profiles            invoices
 ____________       ___________________
|id  Name    |     |profileid   paid   |
|============|     |===================|
|1  Abraham  |     |  2         unpaid |
|2  Martin   |     |  3         unpaid |
|3  John     |     |  3         paid   |
|____________|     |___________________|
```

as can be seen, abraham has 0 invoices, martin has 1 unpaid invoice, and john has 2 invoices; 1 paid, 1 unpaid.

i want to search for:

1. all profiles with paid invoices (john)
2. all profiles with unpaid invoices (john & martin)
3. all profiles with both paid AND unpaid invoice(s) (john)

i can do 1 and 2 fine but im having a problem with step 3.

here is my query for 1;

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT profiles.name 
FROM profiles LEFT JOIN invoices ON (profiles.id=invoices.profileid) 
AND (invoices.paid='paid' OR invoices.paid='unpaid')
WHERE
IFNULL(invoices.paid, '') LIKE 'paid';
```

here is my query for 2;

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT profiles.name 
FROM profiles LEFT JOIN invoices ON (profiles.id=invoices.profileid) 
AND (invoices.paid='paid' OR invoices.paid='unpaid')
WHERE
IFNULL(invoices.paid, '') LIKE 'unpaid';
```

here is my query for 3;

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT profiles.name 
FROM profiles LEFT JOIN invoices ON (profiles.id=invoices.profileid) 
AND (invoices.paid='paid' OR invoices.paid='unpaid')
WHERE
IFNULL(invoices.paid, '') LIKE 'paid' 
AND IFNULL(invoices.paid, '') LIKE 'unpaid'
;
```

as mentioned, 1 & 2 work fine, but 3 gives me 0 results.
any help is much appreciated. thanks

Comment: Would you want a RIGHT join on your last statement since you want multiple dimensions from the invoices table?

Comment: no, a RIGHT join would (and does) only gives me all profiles which have an invoice, it doesnt consider those without any invoices. ie, if i were to just select all profiles; it would only give me martin & john

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the `invoices` table 2 times, in order to get where someone has both paid and unpaid. Try something like -

```
SELECT DISTINCT profiles.name 
FROM profiles 
LEFT JOIN invoices i1 ON (profiles.id=i1.profileid) 
AND (i1.paid='paid')
LEFT JOIN invoices i2 ON (profiles.id=i2.profileid) 
AND (i2.paid='unpaid')
WHERE
IFNULL(i1.paid, '') LIKE 'paid' 
AND IFNULL(i2.paid, '') LIKE 'unpaid';
```

see this sqlfiddle example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee4e2/4

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is a sub query to count the distinct invoice types associated with a profile

```
SELECT `profiles`.`name`
FROM `profiles`
WHERE (
  SELECT count( DISTINCT `subinvoices`.`paid` )
  FROM `invoices` AS `subinvoices`
  WHERE `profiles`.`id` = `subinvoices`.`profileid`
    AND (`subinvoices`.`paid` = 'paid' OR `subinvoices`.`paid` = 'unpaid')
) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with aggregation:

```
select p.*, coalesce(InvoiceInfo, 'NONE')
from profiles p left outer join
     (select profileid,
             (case when sum(paid = 'PAID') > 0 and sum(paid = 'UNPAID') > 0 then 'BOTH'
                   when sum(paid = 'PAID') > 0 then 'PAID-ONLY'
                   when sum(paid = 'UNPAID') > 0 then 'UNPAID-ONLY'
              end) as InvoiceInfo
      from invoices i
     )
     on p.id = i.profileid
```

This allows you to get all three types of information at once.  You can count the people in each group, for instance, by doing:

```
select coalesce(InvoiceInfo, 'NONE'), count(*)
from profiles p left outer join
     (select profileid,
             (case when sum(paid = 'PAID') > 0 and sum(paid = 'UNPAID') > 0 then 'BOTH'
                   when sum(paid = 'PAID') > 0 then 'PAID-ONLY'
                   when sum(paid = 'UNPAID') > 0 then 'UNPAID-ONLY'
              end) as InvoiceInfo
      from invoices i
     )
     on p.id = i.profileid
group by coalesce(InvoiceInfo, 'NONE')
```